# Linear equations with unitary coefficients (combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

Determine the number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_ 4 + x_ 5 = 17, x_ 4 \geq 3$.
My attempt: 
Let $x_ 4 = x_4^{'} + 3$.
The number of solutions from the original equation is equal to the number of solutions from $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_ 4 + x_5= 14$.
Which is $3.060$, but the right answer is $1001$.

Comment: How do you get $3060$?

Comment: $\binom{18}{4} = 3.060$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right solution is not right if you are stating the problem correctly. The number of solutions of the first equation is equivalent to the number of solutions to the second equations as you correctly stated.
 Using stars and bars, the number of solutions of the second equations is $$\binom{14+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{17}{3}=680.$$
**Edit:** In light of your edition of the problem. You are correct and the "right answer" is not.